# Consider defining a bean of type exampleService in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, openapi-generator

I can't run spring boot application while I am getting the next error "Consider defining a bean of type 'exampleService(exampleService is interface)' in your configuration".  exampleService - is coming from openApiGeneration. Should I solve the problem direct from  build.gradle? The code is written in kotlin

Answer (score 1):

In the `build.gradle` file, add the following lines:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas"
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem means that there is no Bean (@Service or @Component) that implements the interface you have mentioned. Hence, Spring cannot find a bean to autowire. Consider adding an implementation of the interface with the @service antonation.